# Why does xlsxwriter write ' at the start of my cells

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, libreoffice

it is my code:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.


# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write_string(0, 0, '99999999001')
worksheet.write_string(0, 1, '99999999001')
worksheet.write_string(0, 2, '99999999001')
worksheet.write_string(0, 3, '99999999001')
worksheet.write_string(0, 4, '99999999001')
worksheet.write_string(0, 5, '99999999001')

workbook.close()
```

I am using

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

XlsxWriter==3.0.1

LibreOffice Calc
Version: 6.4.7.2

In Libre office cells contains this:
'99999999001 - why XlsxWriterr add apostophe to start of my cells?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apostrophe before your number in Libreoffice just notes that the cell format is of type `text`. It isn't actually a part of the cell's content. See this link for more information: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=49046

Just for demonstration, when opening your generated file in Microsoft Excel there are no apostrophes there:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To interpret it as string, not number.

If the value is "000123", by default, XLSX will treat it as number and you will see "123" as cell value. The leading "zero(s)" is missing.

If prefixed with apostrophe `'`, it will be treated as text and you will see the original input which is "000123". The leading zero(s) will not disappear.

The prefixed apostrophe symbol is very useful especially if you are storing tel phone number, social identity number, area code, membership no, or any product code that leading zero is crucial for it's data identification.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i will choose another answer as best because it contains one important detail - It isn't actually a part of the cell's content, but i gave your a plus, thx for help

Comment: @Vasily You're using `worksheet.write_string( )`, which indicates you're storing `text`, not number. So, XLSX will mark the cell value as `TEXT`